# Коллтрекинг на javascript, замена номера в <a href="tel:+7777777777"><span class="ct_phone">+7777777777</span></a>

Tags: javascript

Я пока что не очень разбираюсь в javascript. Нашел в интернете скрипт для замены номера. Все работает, телефон заменяется, но мне нужно чтоб телефон заменялся также в ссылке , сейчас он заменяется только в span с class="ct_phone".

Сам скрипт:

```
/**
 * Static call-tracking script
 * (c) 2015-2017 sipuni.com
 * version 2.0
 */
;(function(root, factory) {

    "use strict";
    if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory();
    } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], factory);
    } else {
        root.sipuniCalltracking = factory();
    }

}(this, function() {

    "use strict";

    /**
     * Default parameters
     * Those parameters are overridden with user parameters passed during initialization
     */
    var default_options = {
        targets: ['.ct_phone'],
        callback: null,
        pattern: '+# (###) ###-##-##',
        sources: {
            'organic':{'ref':/:\/\/(?:www\.)?(google|yandex|mail\.ru|search\.tut\.by|rambler|bing|yahoo)(?:\.(\w+))?/ig},
            'social':{'ref':/:\/\/[^\/]*(twitter|t\.co|facebook|linkedin|vk\.com|odnoklassniki)/ig},
            'email':{'utm_source':'email'},
            'adwords':{'dst': 'gclid='},
            'ydirect_utm':{'utm_source':'direct.yandex.ru'},
            'ydirect_openstat':{'dst': function(subject){
                                            var o = query.getRawParam(subject, '_openstat');
                                            return (o && a2b(o).indexOf('direct.yandex.ru')>-1);
                                       }}
        },
        cookie_key: 'sipunicts',
        cookie_ttl_days: 30*3
    };

    /**
     * querySelectorAll for all browsers
     */
    var select = document.querySelectorAll || function(selector) {
        var style = document.styleSheets[0] || document.createStyleSheet();
        style.addRule(selector, 'foo:bar');
        var all = document.all, resultSet = [];
        for (var i = 0, l = all.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (all[i].currentStyle.foo === 'bar') resultSet[resultSet.length] = all[i];
        }
        style.removeRule(0);
        return resultSet;

    };

    /**
     * Base64 decode for all browsers
     */
    var a2b = window.atob || function a2b(a) {
        var b, c, d, e = {}, f = 0, g = 0, h = "", i = String.fromCharCode, j = a.length;
        for (b = 0; 64 > b; b++) e["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(b)] = b;
        for (c = 0; j > c; c++) for (b = e[a.charAt(c)], f = (f << 6) + b, g += 6; g >= 8; ) ((d = 255 & f >>> (g -= 8)) || j - 2 > c) && (h += i(d));
        return h;
    };

    /**
     * Type detection methods
     */
    var type = {

        isArray: Array.isArray || function(o) {
            return (
                typeof o === 'object' && Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Array]'
                );
        },

        isDictionary: function(o) {
            return (
                typeof o === 'object' && Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Object]'
                );
        },

        isRegExp: function(o) {
            return (
                Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object RegExp]'
                );
        },

        isFunction: function(o) {
            return (
                typeof o === 'function' && Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === '[object Function]'
                );
        }
    };

    /**
     * Query related methods
     */
    var query = {

        /**
         * Returns non decoded value of a query string parameter
         * @param url URL with query string, or just query string part
         * @param name query parameter name
         * @returns string a string with parameter value or null of no parameter exist
         */
        getRawParam: function(url, name){
            var regex = new RegExp(name+"=([^&]+)");
            var found = regex.exec(url);
            return (found !== null ? found[1] : null);
        },
        /**
         * Returns a URL-decoded value of query string parameter
         * @param url url with query string, or just query string part
         * @param name query parameter name
         * @returns string A string with parameter value or null of no parameter exist
         */
        getParam: function(url, name){
            var found = query.getRawParam(url, name);
            return (found !== null ? decodeURIComponent(found) : null);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Cookie related methods
     */
    var cookies = {

        /**
         * Returns a top level domain from a subdomain
         * @param domain string with domain or subdomain
         * @returns string top level domain or empty string for the localhost
         */
        topDomain: function(domain) {
            if (!domain) {
                return null;
            }
            var parts = domain.split('.');
            if (parts.length > 1) {
                var result = parts[ parts.length - 2 ] + '.' + parts[ parts.length - 1 ];
                if (result.indexOf(':') + 1){
                    return result.substr(0, result.length-5)
                }
                else {
                    return result
                }
            }
            return '';
        },

        /**
         * Sets a cookie
         * @param name cookie name
         * @param value cookie value
         * @param exdays cookie duration in days. put here null for the session only cookie
         */
        set: function (name, value, exdays) {
            var exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            var c_value = encodeURIComponent(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            var top_domain = cookies.topDomain(window.location.hostname);
            var cookie = name + "=" + c_value + "; path=/" + "; domain=" + (top_domain ? '.'+top_domain : '');
            document.cookie = cookie;
        },

        /**
         * Gets a cookie value
         * @param name cookie name
         * @returns string A string with cookie value or null if no cookie exist
         */
        get: function (name){
            var val = document.cookie;
            var start = val.indexOf(" " + name + "=");
            if (start == -1) {
                start = val.indexOf(name + "=");
            }
            if (start == -1) {
                val = null;
            }else{
                start = val.indexOf("=", start) + 1;
                var end = val.indexOf(";", start);
                if (end == -1) {
                    end = val.length;
                }
                val = decodeURIComponent(val.substring(start, end));
            }
            return val;
        },

        /**
         * Deletes a cookie
         * @param name cookie name to delete
         */
        delete: function (name){
            cookies.set(name, null, -10);
        }

    };

    /**
     * Parameters manipulation methods
     */
    var dict = {

        /**
         * Updated one dictionary with the elements of another one.
         * @param dict_dst destination dictionary
         * @param dict_src source dictionary
         */
        update: function  (dict_dst, dict_src) {
            var is_array = type.isArray(dict_src);
            dict_dst = dict_dst || (is_array?[]:{});
            for (var prop in dict_src) {
                var v = dict_src[prop];
                if (type.isDictionary(v)) {
                    var d = dict_dst.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? dict_dst[prop] : null;
                    dict_dst[prop] = dict.update(d, v);
                } else {
                    dict_dst[prop] = v;
                }
            }
            return dict_dst;
        },

        /**
         * Merges two dictionaries and creates a new dictionary with results.
         * @param dict1 first dictionary
         * @param dict2 second dictionar
         * @returns object A new dictionary containing both dictionaries
         */
        merge: function(dict1, dict2){
            var result = {};
            dict.update(result, dict1);
            dict.update(result, dict2);
            return result;
        },

        /**
         * Returns dictionary keys
         * @param dict dictionary to search for
         * @returns Array An array with keys
         */
        keys: function(dictionary){
            var keys = [];
            for (var key in dictionary) {
                if (dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    keys.push(key);
                }
            }
            return keys;
        },

        /**
         * Returns a value from the dictionary or default value
         * @param dictionary
         * @param key
         * @param default_value
         * @returns a value of default_value
         */
        getVal: function(dictionary, key, default_value) {
            if (!dictionary || !dictionary.hasOwnProperty(key))
                return default_value;
            return dictionary[key];
        }

    };


    var actions = {

        place: function(targets, value) {
            for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
                targets[i].innerHTML = value;
            }
        },

        getTargets: function(selectors) {
            return select.call(document, selectors);
        },

        execCallback: function(phone, src_url, dst_url, options, template) {
            var cb = dict.getVal(options, 'callback', null);
            if (cb && type.isFunction(cb)){
                return cb(phone, src_url, dst_url, options, template);
            }
            return null;
        }

    };

    /**
     * Finds a phone number matching conditions
     */
    var tracker = {

        find: function(sources, phones, src_url, dst_url){

            for (var i=0; i<phones.length; i++){
                var phone = phones[i];
                var src = phone['src'];

                if(sources.hasOwnProperty(src)){

                    if(tracker.match(sources[src], src_url, dst_url)){
                        return phone;
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        },

        match: function(source, src_url, dst_url){

            var subject=null;
            var condition = null;
            var keys = dict.keys(source);

            for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){

                var key = keys[i];

                if( key.indexOf('utm_')>-1 ){
                    subject = query.getParam(dst_url, key);
                    condition = source[key];
                }else if( key=='ref' ){
                    subject = src_url;
                    condition = source[key];
                }else if( key == 'dst' ){
                    subject = dst_url;
                    condition = source[key];
                }
            }

            if(!subject || !condition){
                return false;
            }

            return (
                (type.isRegExp(condition) && condition.exec(subject)) ||
                (typeof(condition)=='string' && subject.indexOf(condition)>-1) ||
                (type.isFunction(condition) && condition(subject))
            );
        },

        findBySrc: function(phones, src){
            for (var i=0; i<phones.length; i++){
                var phone = phones[i];
                if (phone.hasOwnProperty('src') && phone['src'] == src){
                    return phone;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Phone number formatting support
     */
    var template = {

        /**
         * Formats the phone number, removes a plus sign for the 8-800 numbers.
         * @param string phone number
         * @param string pattern, 9 as a placeholder. E.g. +9 (999) 999-99-99
         * @returns {string} formatter phone number
         */
        format_number: function (num, pattern){

            if(num.toString().match(/^8800/) && pattern && pattern[0]=='+'){
                pattern = pattern.replace(/^\+/, '');
            }
            return template.format(num, pattern);
        },

        /**
         * Formats the phone number using the pattern
         * @param string phone number
         * @param string pattern, 9 as a placeholder. E.g. +9 (999) 999-99-99
         * @returns {string} formatter phone number
         */
        format: function (num, pattern){

            if(!(typeof(num) === "string")){
                num = num.toString();
            }

            if(!num)
                return '';

            if(typeof(pattern) === "undefined" || !pattern)
                return num;

            var arr_res=[];
            var num_counter = num.length-1;

            for(var i=pattern.length-1; i>=0; i--){
                var s = pattern[i];
                if(s=='#'){
                    if(num_counter>=0){
                        arr_res.push(num[num_counter--]);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    arr_res.push(s);
                }
            }
            return arr_res.reverse().join('');
        }
    };

    return function(user_options, wnd) {

        var options = dict.merge(default_options, user_options);
        var phone = null;
        var sources = options['sources'];
        var phones = options['phones'];
        var src_url = wnd.document.referrer;
        var dst_url = wnd.location.href;

        // find from cookies first
        var existing_src = cookies.get(options['cookie_key']);
        if(existing_src && sources.hasOwnProperty(existing_src)){

            phone = tracker.findBySrc(phones, existing_src);

        }

        // find from urls
        if( phone === null ){

            phone = tracker.find(
                sources,
                phones,
                src_url,
                dst_url);

            // store in cookies
            if(phone !== null){
                cookies.set(options['cookie_key'], phone['src'], options['cookie_ttl_days']);
            }
        }

        // insert phone numbers
        if (phone){
            var targets = options['targets'];
            var numbers = phone['phone'];
            for(var i=0, len=Math.min(targets.length, numbers.length); i<len; i++){
                var elements = actions.getTargets(targets[i]);
                var number = template.format_number(numbers[i], options['pattern']);
                actions.place(elements, number);
            }
        }

        // callback
        actions.execCallback(phone, src_url, dst_url, options, template);
    };

}));


<script>
  sipuniCalltracking({
    sources: {
       'yadirect':{'utm_source': 'direct.yandex.ru'},
       'articles':{'ref': /(habrahabr|oborot.ru)/ig}
    },
    phones: [
       {'src':'yadirect', 'phone':['+74951111114']},
       {'src':'articles', 'phone':['+74952222224']}
    ],
    pattern:'+# (###) ###-##-##'
  }, window);
</script>
```

Comment: Вы бы ещё весь проект сюда скинули)) Пожалуйста, уберите из кода всё лишнее (то что не относится к замену номера и вашей проблемной части). Так всем будет удобнее воспринимать и читать ваш код

Comment: Ну так добавь ссылке `class="ct_phone"`

Comment: я добавил, меняет только в span

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос таким коротким кодом, может кому пригодится

```
var check = window.location.href.indexOf("gclid="),
    phone = document.querySelectorAll(".phone");
if (check > -1) {
    function set_cookie(e, o, t, c, n) {
        var r = e + "=" + escape(o);
        t && (r += "; expires=" + new Date(t, c, n).toGMTString());
        document.cookie = r;
    }
    phone.forEach((e) => {
        (e.href = "tel:+375251111111"), (e.textContent = "+375251111111");
    });
    var name = "change_phone",
        value = "cpc",
        current_date = new Date(),
        cookie_year = current_date.getFullYear() + 1,
        cookie_month = current_date.getMonth(),
        cookie_day = current_date.getDate();
    set_cookie(name, value, cookie_year, cookie_month, cookie_day);
} else console.log("Яндекс");
function get_cookie(e) {
    var o = document.cookie.match("(^|;) ?" + e + "=([^;]*)(;|$)");
    return o ? unescape(o[2]) : null;
}
var x = get_cookie("change_phone");
"cpc" == x &&
    phone.forEach((e) => {
        (e.href = "tel:+375251111111"), (e.textContent = "+375251111111");
    });
```